# Navigating html tree with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data with beautifulsoup on python (url:`http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/tipping-the-velvet_999/index.html`)

When the data is first occurrence, no problem like

```py
titlebook = soup.find("h1")
titlebook = titlebook.text
```

but i want to scrape different values, further in page, like upc, price incl.tax, etc
Upc value is first and i have it running `universal_product_code= soup.find("tr").find("td").text`

I tried so many solutions to access the other ones (i've read beautifulsoup documentation and tried lot of things but it didn't really help me)
So my question is, how to access specific values in a tree where tags are same? I joined a screenshot of the tree to help you understand what i'm talking about

[image: tree_screenshot]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Include the HTML snippet as formatted text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you want to find price (excluding tax), you can use `string=` parameter in `.find` and then search for text in next `<td>`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/tipping-the-velvet_999/index.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

# get "Price (excl. tax)" from the table:
key = "Price (excl. tax)"
print("{}: {}".format(key, soup.find("th", string=key).find_next("td").text))
```

Prints:

```
Price (excl. tax): £53.74
```

---

Or: Use CSS selector:

```
print(soup.select_one('th:-soup-contains("Price (excl. tax)") + td').text)
```